Error in Haskell call to equation with expected type
I'm performing the following call to haskell method
rollD6 ::  (RandomGen g, Int a) => Int -> ([a], g)
rollD6 times =  roll Die6 times (mkStdGen 6)

rollD6InRange :: (RandomGen g, Int a) => Int -> Int -> Int -> ([a], g)
rollD6InRange times start end = rollR Die6 times start end (mkStdGen 6)

class Roll a where
  roll :: (RandomGen g) => a -> Int -> g -> ([Int], g)
  rollR :: (RandomGen g) => a -> Int -> Int -> Int -> g -> ([Int], g)

instance Roll Die where
  roll Die6 times = generateIntRandomsArray 1 6 times
  roll Die4 times = generateIntRandomsArray 1 4 times
  roll Die20 times = generateIntRandomsArray 1 20 times
  roll Die100 times = generateIntRandomsArray 1 100 times

  rollR Die6  times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times
  rollR Die4 times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times
  rollR Die20 times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times
  rollR Die100 times first last = generateIntRandomsArray first last times

generateIntRandomsArray :: (Eq a, Random a, Num a, RandomGen g) => a -> a -> a -> g -> ([a], g)
generateIntRandomsArray start end = generate
    where generate 0 generator = ([], generator)
          generate numberElements generator =
              let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (start,end) generator
                  (restOfList, finalGenerator) = generate (numberElements-1) newGenerator
              in  (value:restOfList, finalGenerator)

and I'm getting the following error
src/Merp/Die/Boundary/RollADie.hs:11:26: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature:
        rollD6 :: (RandomGen g, Int a) => Int -> ([a], g)
   |
11 | rollD6 ::  (RandomGen g, Int a) => Int -> ([a], g)
   |                          ^^^^^

src/Merp/Die/Boundary/RollADie.hs:14:32: error:
    • Expected kind ‘* -> Constraint’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type signature:
        rollD6InRange :: (RandomGen g, Int a) =>
                         Int -> Int -> Int -> ([a], g)
    |
 14 | rollD6InRange :: (RandomGen g, Int a) => Int -> Int -> Int -> ([a], g)
    |                                ^^^^^

I've been playing with the parameters of the call, but I haven't been able to figure it out what is happening . Could you please give me a clue about what it's left ?

This API is very strange. Are there really more instances of this type? If not, don't make this a class. But if so, I guess I would at the very least expect this to be a multi-parameter type class or a class with an associated type for the output values; surely not all random "specifications" are for producing Ints. 1/2

I would also expect repetition to be done outside the class; make the methods only have stuff that differs between instances. rollR probably shouldn't exist at all; generateIntRandomsArray already does the same thing, without the weird ignored first argument. Why does gIRA force the repetition count to be the same type as the random type being generated? 2/2

Int is not a typeclass, so:
rollD6 :: (RandomGen g, Int a) => Int -> ([a], g)
rollD6 times = roll Die6 times (mkStdGen 6)
makes not much sense: you substitute a for Int, so:
rollD6 :: RandomGen g => Int -> ([Int], g)
rollD6 times = roll Die6 times (mkStdGen 6)
The same holds for rollD6InRange.
I would also advise to keep the type for the range and the number of elements, separate, so:
generateIntRandomsArray :: (Random a, Integral b, RandomGen g) => a -> a -> b -> g -> ([a], g)
generateIntRandomsArray start end = generate
  where
    generate 0 generator = ([], generator)
    generate numberElements generator =
      let (value, newGenerator) = randomR (start, end) generator
          (restOfList, finalGenerator) = generate (numberElements -1) newGenerator
       in (value : restOfList, finalGenerator)
this allows us for example to generate from a sequence of Chars, Bools, Floats, or anything else that is an instance of Random [Hackage], for example:
ghci> generateIntRandomsArray 'a' 'z' 10 (mkStdGen 0)
("nlrkwldbji",1695805043 1336516156)


@Yago: Not something you would normally do, but with certain extensions (for example, TypeFamilies) you can use Int ~ a as a constraint; the ~ "operator" says that a and Int must be unified for the function to type check (i.e., it asserts that a must be Int).

Nice . Thanks for helping me . Just a newbie trying to learn .
